# Qual a melhor forma de rodar uma aplicação java como Serviço no Windows (32 ou 64 bits)?

Tags: java, services

O que é necessário fazer para rodar um aplicativo Java (sem interface visual) como serviço do Windows. O programa usa basicamente a API de Filesystem e a API de rede (java.net, java.io e java.nio)

Se for necessário fazer build a partir dos fontes gostaria de usar GNU C++ em vez de Visual Studio.

Alguma dica ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

De acordo com uma [pergunta semelhante](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app) no stackoverflow.com você pode utilizar ferramentas do Apache Commons Deamon para realizar isso.

Em específico existe o [Procrun](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) que é um conjunto de aplicativos que permite que você possa empacotar aplicações Java como serviços rodando em plano de fundo no Windows.

Eu consigo imaginar outra possibilidade, em .Net criar um programa como serviço do windows é uma tarefa 'trivial' e existem [algumas formas](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/tutorial.html) de integrar bibliotecas Java para serem utilizadas com .Net, você pode combinar isso e criar um serviço .Net que utilize suas funções desenvolvidas em Java.

Answer (score 1):

O [Install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) cria instaladores para aplicações Java, que por sua vez podem ser instaladas como serviços no Windows. É um produto pago, mas permite gerenciar vários detalhes de uma instalação/configuração de serviço. Fica a dica.