# Aplicação Java rodando como serviço do Windows

Tags: java, mysql, web-service, rest, integração

Preciso desenvolver uma aplicação em Java que deve rodar em filiais da empresa como um serviço do Windows. O cenário é o seguinte:

- Preciso obter algumas informações do banco de dados de um software de terceiro que não poderá ser alterado. Porém eu tenho a senha e o usuário do banco de dados (MySQL) p/ que eu tenha acesso aos dados que preciso.
- A aplicação que vou desenvolver, precisa obter periodicamente determinados dados do banco de dados (MySQL) da aplicação de terceiro e enviá-los para um Web Service REST.

Qual seria a melhor forma de desenvolver esta solução?

Comment: @Bacco vc sugere, talvez editar o título da pergunta p/ ficar mais claro?

Comment: Não só o título. Se são duas dúvidas numa pergunta só, seria melhor separar em duas postagens, senão você depende de quem domine as duas situações para poder obter respostas, e além disso, ficaria extenso e confuso. Fora isso, a parte da auditoria precisa ser melhor explicada. Sugeriria tirar a auditoria dessa aqui e abrir uma nova só da auditoria. Mas com mais detalhes do que você precisa exatamente.

Comment: Realmente eu não tinha pensado nessa situação, que fico dependente de quem domine as duas situações. Reformulei a pergunta, acha que ficou melhor dessa maneira?
Vou esperar obter uma solução p/ este caso em especifico e depois eu crio uma outra postagem sobre a auditoria.
Muito obrigado @Bacco

Comment: Gicobbe, dica: num caso como este, é legal deixar o aviso na pergunta, do tipo *"conferi [tal-pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6916/qual-a-melhor-forma-de-rodar-uma-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-java-como-servi%c3%a7o-no-windows-32-ou-6) mas não resolver por `tal-motivo`"*... ps: se por acaso a pergunta for fechada por engano, pode agilizar indo no [chat] ou no [meta].